# Too many arguments to Wait for condition in Robot Framework?

Tags: conditional-statements, robotframework

I have the following line in Robot Framework

```
Wait for condition  'Get element attribute  id:something  attribute=something_else'  ==  'abc'
```

I think this is pretty self explanatory: I want to wait until `Get element attribute` returns `abc`.

However, this returns an error message

```
Wait for condition expected 1 to 3 arguments, got 5.
```

On an abstract level, this error message is pretty clear but I don't understand how it applies here. The five arguments it refers to are arguments not to `Wait for condition` but to `Get element attribute.` I want to send two arguments to `Wait for condition` that should be equal, the return value from `Get element attribute` and the string `abc`.

How do I write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the other answer it was rightfully pointed out the `Wait For Condition` keyword is just for js code being ran in the browser. Here's how to do what you want with the [builtin keyword `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) and [SeleniumLibrary's `Element Attribute Value Should Be`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Element%20Attribute%20Value%20Should%20Be):

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    retry=1 minute    retry_interval=5 seconds    Element Attribute Value Should Be    id:something  attribute=something_else    expected=abc
```

The `Element Attribute Value Should Be` is new in Selenium Library v3.2, if you don't have this version yet, here's a sample implementation:

```
Attribute Value Should Be
    [Documentation]    Fails if the element's attribute is not the expected one
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${attribute}    ${expected}

    ${value}=    Get Element Attribute    ${locator}    ${attribute}
    Run Keyword If    """${value}""" != """${expected}"""
    ...     Fail    The attribute's value is different from the expected: ${value} != ${expected}
```

Comment: When I try your example I get the following error message `ValueError: Invalid time string 'retry=1m'.` I have tried other formats such as `60s` but with the same result. When I look at your keyword it only receives 3 arguments, how can you call it with 5 arguments? Thank you.

Comment: For the retry value it was my mistake, sorry; changed it to a correct one ("1 minute", "60 seconds" will also do - the full word for the period). I don't understand what do you mean by calling the keyword with 5 arguments - they are 3; the way it is called in the example is with "named arguments" - argument_name=value.

Comment: Isn't the retry-arguments arguments? How are they handled by the receiving KW? I don't understand how they are used in the KW.

Comment: `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` has 3 arguments - `retry`, `retry_inteval`, and - the keyword to run. So `retry=1 minute    retry_interval=5 seconds` are being handled by the `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`, and never get to your keyword. The first thing that comes after them (the 3rd argument) is the keyword you are waiting to succeed - `Element Attribute Value Should Be` in this case. And every argument after the 3rd one (the target keyword name), is passed to it, to use as calling arguments. So `id:something attribute=something_else expected=abc` are args for `Element Attribute Value Should Be`

Comment: Sorry for being blind and stupid. Not yet really used to RF's slightly odd syntax.

Comment: No worries, I guess RF can be a bit intimidating in the beginning :). If you're happy with the answer - don't be shy to accept it ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is not how `wait for condition` works. You can't give it a keyword. You must give it a javascript expression.

From the documentation:

> The condition can be arbitrary JavaScript expression but it must return a value to be evaluated. See Execute JavaScript for information about accessing content on pages.

Comment: Hmm, is there another keyword I could use as I want? Or how do I write a Javascript that performs the comparison I try to achieve in my question?

Comment: @d-b: you can use the built-in keyword [wait until keyword succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) but I personally don't recommend that approach just because there's almost always a better solution. You can do what you want with just a little bit of javascript, and it would be much more efficient than `wait until keyword succeeds`.